# How to set verbosity of a uvm_sequence from command line?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What's the best way to set the verbosity of a `uvm_sequence` from command line?

I know it is possible to set the verbosity of ALL sequences on a sequencer like:

`+uvm_set_verbosity=*my_sequencer,_ALL_,UVM_HIGH,run`

However, the sequencer has tons of sequences that are spewing too much info. Any way to just get the one sequence I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the messages coming from the sequences a unique ID (or one that can be match with a regular expression), then the second argument to `+uvm_set_verbosity` can be used to select the messages you want to silence.

Comment: Yes, that's a good code practice to include a unique string in all the messages of your sequence. However, I'm dealing with other people's code here, and such practice was not followed.

Comment: Your only other option is very slow and ugly - write a report catcher that knows the text of the messages you want to allow(or disallow) and catch ( or throw)  by some piece of that message.